# Inflating views in for loop with different identity?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, android-layout

I am inflating layout in view in a for loop and then adding views in Array like:

```
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList();
for (Result datalist : arraylist){

View view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlayout, null); 
/*View modification code here....   
.............
.............
.............*/

views.add(view);
};
```

The problem is when i get views from arraylist even by index like views.get(i) it returning only last view. I want to get all views to be able to work on all views.

Here is the code where i am getting views from arrays.

```
 for (View v : views) {
 //            if (insertPoint != null) {
 //                if (views != null) {
 //                    if (rel_leftright != null) {
        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        insertPoint.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        if (v.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
            rel_leftright.setVisibility(GONE);
        } else {
            rel_leftright.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
  //                    }
  //                }
  //            }
    }
```

But this code returning only working on last view in array and i need to act on all views.

Please Help me to get out of this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

First I am missing something: 
 - Why are you trying to work with the views (/*View modification code here.... ) before you have created all of them? First craete them in the loop and the iterate over views Array and there call the modification code. 
- Are you sure you don't want to pass a parent?

```
View view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlayout, null);
```

Even if you don't want to be attached you can call:

```
View view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlayout, parent, false);
```

And in general it is not possible to fill ArrayList with values and not to find them... Please log the size of datalist, then the size of views. The most probably should match.

And also please note that by the line: /*View modification code here.... **not all views are created. You first need to finish the loop.**

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i think that this is not really my issue. I am editing the code and adding the snippet of code where i am getting the getting views from arrays